# mcmapply result in "long" or "wide" format

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply

The code below generates results in "wide" format, with row names "i_var" and "j_var" respectively. Instead, I would like results in "long" format, with 2 variables: "i_var"  and "j_var" and each row corresponding to each "iteration".

```
i_list<-c(1:3) 
j_list<-c(4:6)

aFUN <- function(i,j) {  
        
c("i_var"=i,"j_var"=j)  

}

results<-mcmapply(aFUN,i_list,j_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `mcmapply`, the first argument should be `FUN`

```
library(parallel)
do.call(rbind, mcmapply(aFUN, i_list,j_list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
#     i_var j_var
#[1,]     1     5
#[2,]     2     6
#[3,]     3     5
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't seem to do it. it gives me 1 column and 6 rows. i'd like 2 columns (each var name) and 3 rows.

Comment: @Raimundo In `R 4.0`, I get two columns as in the updated answer

Comment: i'm on version 3.6.1. is that what it is?

Comment: @Raimundo it could be and also the arguments in your function seems to be not in the order it is showed in the documentation for `mcmapply`

Comment: i checked the order of arguments, and that doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: i also changed a bit the example, as i noticed vectors where not of the same length, they should be.

Comment: @Raimundo in my documentation, it shows usage as `mcmapply(FUN, ...,
         MoreArgs = NULL, SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE,
         mc.preschedule = TRUE, mc.set.seed = TRUE,
         mc.silent = FALSE, mc.cores = getOption("mc.cores", 2L),
         mc.cleanup = TRUE, affinity.list = NULL)`

Comment: Suggestion: Try to figure it out using `base::mapply()` - fewer arguments to worry about. 
 When you've got that working, then you should be able to use the same arguments with `parallel::mcmcapply()`.

Comment: @akrun, yes, oddly enough it still works, and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @akrun is the canonical one in this case. As an alternative, you can transpose the result of mcmapply:

```
library(parallel)
results <- mcmapply(FUN = aFUN, i = i_list, j = j_list)
t(results)

#      i_var j_var
# [1,]     1     4
# [2,]     2     5
# [3,]     3     6
```

Comment: if i_list and j_list are BIG, is there any drawback to this solution?

Comment: It's just as time-efficient as the next-best solution when dealing with large vectors, provided `results` does not become a `data.frame` before being transposed.